# Как выбрать зону времени?

Tags: дата, javascript

Добрый день, подскажите как выбрать зону времени например Красноярска?

```
function startTime()
    {
    var tm=new Date();
    var h=tm.getHours();
    var m=tm.getMinutes();
    var s=tm.getSeconds();
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    document.getElementById('txx').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
    }
    function checkTime(i)
    {
    if (i<10)
    {
    i="0" + i;
    }
    return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если погуглить хоть чутьчуть?
[Упралявляем timezone через javascript](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/)

Описание вообще класса `Date` вот [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), присмотритесь к функциям типа `setUTCDate()`

Comment: вообщем смысл брать время не локальное пользовательское, а время UTC и добавлять к нему сдвиг, вот и вся магия :)